# Rotated text gets cropped

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

When I trying to rotate `Column` with `Text` with `fillMaxWidth()`, all my long text fits to the screen:

```
@Composable
private fun Content() {
    Column(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth() // VARIANT 1
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .background(Color.White)
    ) {
        BoxWithConstraints(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            val W = this.maxWidth
            val H = this.maxHeight

            Column(
                Modifier
                    .rotate(-90f)
                    .height(W)
                    .width(H),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Text",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .wrapContentHeight()
                        .padding(end = 10.dp),
                    maxLines = 1,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.End
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

But when I trying to limit root `Column` width with `200.dp`, my text line seems to be cut to same width, `200.dp`:

```
@Composable
private fun Content() {
    Column(
        Modifier
            .width(200.dp) // VARIANT 2
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .background(Color.White)
    ) {
        BoxWithConstraints(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            val W = this.maxWidth
            val H = this.maxHeight

            Column(
                Modifier
                    .rotate(-90f)
                    .height(W)
                    .width(H),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Text",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .wrapContentHeight()
                        .padding(end = 10.dp),
                    maxLines = 1,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.End
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Why is it so strange, and how can I fit long rotated text line into the narrow Column?

UPD:
The final result that I want to achieve is the left side AppBar like on screenshot below.

[image: left side AppBar]

But I cannot fit title text within, it is truncated.

Comment: Do you want the text to be wrapped?

Comment: Please explain your question.

Answer (score 1):

Rotation always occurs around the center of the inner content AFTER the parent container has already been resized. This means that you end up with cropped text. To achieve what you want, your left column AppBar and right column content need to be placed inside a Box that fills the entire screen. You can then rotate the text as long as it is centered. You must then adjust the offset of the text AFTER rotation to place it in the correct location. The Box must also have a transparent background. The amount of offset you use for the text will depend on the length of the text. Another possible solution is to create a custom layout and use the measured placeables and relocate them in the correct position. But even that requires adding offsets. So the solution shown here is probably easier to implement.

```
Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.TopStart) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(start = 100.dp)
            .background(color = Color.Yellow)
    ) {
        Text("Content goes here...")
    }

    IconButton(modifier = Modifier.offset(x = 40.dp, y = 10.dp), onClick = {}) {
        Icon(
            modifier = Modifier
                .requiredWidth(50.dp)
                .requiredHeight(50.dp)
                ,
            imageVector = Icons.Filled.Reply,
            contentDescription = ""
        )
    }

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(color = Color.Transparent), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        Text(
            "This is a very long text that should not get cut off",
            modifier = Modifier.rotate(-90f).offset(x = 130.dp, y = -140.dp),
            softWrap = false
        )
    } }
```

[image: Rotated Text]

Comment: Do you mean that I need to remove width and height modifiers from nested Column? I've tried to remove width, remove height and remove both. I does not works correctly.

Comment: You only have to remove .width(200.dp). I tried your code and it works when you do this. The nested column is fine. It's the first column that is causing the problem. I updated my post to show you the full code.

Comment: But I need to fit text within NARROW Column (200.dp). I'm trying to implement left side AppBar.

Comment: You should post an image showing what you want you your AppBar to look like when it is done otherwise you will end up going back and forth in long discussions. You need to show the complete AppBar how it looks and not just some rotated text. The code you posted doesn't really make sense because no one can understand why you are using a Column with a nested BoxWithConstraints.

Comment: I've updated my question with the AppBar screenshot.

Comment: So you just want two columns? In the first column is the rotated text and the second column is your content?

Comment: Yes, I want that.

Comment: Thank you, but reusable AppBar is preferable for me.

Comment: Not sure what you are referring to by "AppBar". A custom AppBar the way you've shown it in your code or the one provided by Android? If it's your own custom AppBar, then it IS reusable. If it's Android's AppBar, then you really should have included that in your post.

Comment: I mean my own custom AppBar.

Comment: I've solved my problem.

Comment: So in the end you still ended up using offsets as I showed in my example.

Comment: Yes, but I also need LazyRow to get Text not cropped.

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I've found a nice solution for my problem with `LazyRow`:

```
val APP_BAR_WIDTH = 200.dp
val TEXT_MAX_WIDTH = 1000.dp
val OFFSET = (TEXT_MAX_WIDTH - APP_BAR_WIDTH) / 2

@Composable
private fun Content() {
    Column(
        Modifier
            .width(APP_BAR_WIDTH) 
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .background(Color.White)
    ) {
        val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
        val state = rememberLazyListState()
        LazyRow(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(APP_BAR_WIDTH)
                .fillMaxHeight(),
            state = state
        ) {
            item {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .rotate(-90f)
                        .height(APP_BAR_WIDTH)
                         .offset(x = -OFFSET, y = -OFFSET),
                     verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
                 ) {
                     Text(
                         text = "Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Text",
                         modifier = Modifier
                             .width(TEXT_MAX_WIDTH),
                         softWrap = false,
                         textAlign = TextAlign.End
                     )
                 }
             }
         }
         state.disableScrolling(scope)
     }
 }
 
 fun LazyListState.disableScrolling(scope: CoroutineScope) {
     scope.launch {
         scroll(scrollPriority = MutatePriority.PreventUserInput) {
             awaitCancellation()
         }
     }
 }
```

Here is implementation of my `SideAppBar` on github:

[SideAppBar implementation](https://github.com/tabatsky/RussianRockSongBook4/blob/master/sideAppBar/src/main/java/jatx/sideappbar/SideAppBar.kt)

Here is some result screenshots:

[image: Screenshot1]

[image: Screenshot2]