# 90º rotated textview gets size to display text as the horizontal space

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a textview where I want to show text in vertical (just like rotated 90º). With `android:rotation="-90"` you can get this.

If the text would have no rotation, and you would like to fit a sentence, you would first look at the width of the textview, since text will try to be in 1 line. Since I rotate the text, here I expect to see the height of the object. However, Android is still considering the width. I need to fix the size of the width, but this causes me a problem for the text: Although the textview has a big vertical dimension and text would fit, Android thinks it needs to use the width to calculate the available space. At the end this causes me overflow of the text, appearing for example, just one word as multiple lines of 1 char.

How can I make android to understand that the space for the lenght to fit the text is now the vertical, instead of the horizontal?

Comment: All measurements and layouts occur prior to the rotation being made. If that doesn't make sense, post some more information such as code and screen shots and what you expect to happen.

Comment: you got to handle it with java. i think this will help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70014899/rotated-text-gets-cropped