# Rotated long text does not shows normally in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, jetpack

when i rotate text inside box it gets the wrong position.

Here is my code:

```
Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .fillMaxHeight(0.2f)
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(5.dp))
            .shadow(5.dp)
            .background(Color(0xFFD88EDD))
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .fillMaxWidth(0.12f)
                .background(Color(0xFFC27FC6)),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "27 DECC",
                color = Color.White,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                fontFamily = fontFamily,
                fontSize = 13.sp,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .rotate(-90f)
                    .background(Color.Red),
            )
        }
    }
```

I have already tried to use softWrap property, but in this case the text get croped, like on the first picture. May be somebody answered on this question here: [Rotated text gets cropped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70014899/rotated-text-gets-cropped), but this solution did not help in my case.

In first picture i use softWrap, in second i dont.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYlIj.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7w87M.png)

Comment: can you explain exactly how it cropped and how you want it to be?

Comment: Chirag Thummar, you can see it on the first picture, it does not show the full text. The full text is 27 DECC, but it shows only 27 DEC. One letter is cropped. I want to show 27 DECC

Comment: Its because of You are using ```fillMaxWidth(0.12f)``` in ```Box```. Remove it and check its works

Comment: @ChiragThummar, it works, big thanks to you